While running unit test it RustRover, RustRover recompile all dependencies every time
When i run a unit test in RustRover,the IDE recompile every dependencies every time,even though i did not do any change.
But when I run cargo test in command line , it could use compile cache correctly,that means i don`t need to wait for minutes for just a single line change .
So which setting in RustRover leads to this situation exactly?
Ive search several relevant articles abount this issue on StackOverFloat.But most of them are describing the issues on VSCode , not in RustRover. I guess there is a similar setting in RoverRover,but i didnt find it.

Hi!
Does this happen in every project (e.g., Hello World) or only in a specific one?
Does it help if you disable the Test Tool Window under Settings | Advanced Settings | Rust?
Is it only the unit test that triggers a recompilation of the entire project, or does this happen after building or running?

Thanks to your remind , i found that this situation just happend on several sepcific test cases, other cases are ok. But i really don`t know why yet······
